# Clearing all data from data grid view

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview

I have three data grid views I am processing data and showing it on first then taking from first and processing and showing on second, Now I want to reuse my first data grid view but it is not clear, it has old data which makes problem means old columns and values.I have tried:

```
    datagridview2.datasource=null;   // didn't  work
    datagridview2.columns.clear();   // didn't work
```

I want data grid view to be *clear* as new , please help

Comment: To which the datagridview is bounded to? I mean dataset or datatable or something else?

Answer (score 2):

```
datagridview2.Rows.Clear();
datagridview2.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
GridView1.DataSource = null;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: The question is tagged WinForms `DataGridView` not ASP.Net `GridView`. No `DataBind` method in `DataGridView`...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot... My assumption was to clear the columns as you said you have tried...

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= datagridview2.ColumnCount - 1; i++) {
 datagridview2.Columns.Remove(datagridview2.Columns(0).Name);}
```

Let me know how it works for you...

Thanks!